# What is the maximum and minimum value of the following function?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I came across a question in the book Calculus for the Practical Man. The question stated to find the maximum or minimum value of the following function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\cos^2x - \sin 2x$$

I tried to find first the critical value by differentiating this function to get:

$$f'(x) = \frac{-\sin2x}{4}-2\cos2x$$

However, I am unable to solve it further to get the value of $x$ for the maximum or minimum. Can someone please help me out? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Both answers at this point make use of a non-calculus trigonometric assertion about the maximum value of $a\cos x + b\sin x.$ Many (most?) U.S. beginning calculus students would not know this, but a straightforward “find the derivative and set the derivative equal to zero” approach that one would expect to work in an introductory calculus text doesn’t appear to work. I got $\tan(2x) = -8$ (not a recognizable value of the tangent function), which leads to quadratic equation in $\tan x$ when applying the double angle formula, **(continued)**

Comment: which when solved also does not give a recognizable value of the tangent function. Of course, the values of the tangent function can be “pushed through” with some work to obtain max/min values of the function (evaluate sine and cosine functions at the inverse-tangent values), but it seems to me this is beyond what would be expected in a “Calculus for the Practical Man” text. If your text appears to assume somewhere that its readers would know the non-calculus trigonometric assertion I stated earlier, then it would be helpful to include that in your question.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro the trigonometric assertion after all can be proved using basic compound angle identities and noting the image of the $\sin$ (or $\cos$) function. I think this knowledge is already a part of pre-calculus courses.

Comment: @Sahaj: I agree, but that doesn't mean students will remember it or even think of using it when asked in a calculus text/class to find max/min. Spending a book section or two (or two to three lectures) discussing the first and second derivative tests and such, and then having this be an exercise seems a bit [underhanded](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/underhanded) to me. My guess is that the text included some kind of warning before this, or there were prior worked examples showing that trotting out calculus without thinking sometimes doesn't work very well.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I looked in the book but couldn't find something of that sort. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite, $$f(x)=\frac18\left(1+\cos(2x)-8\sin(2x)\right)$$
Note that $a\sin x +b\cos x$ has maximum $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and minimum $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Thus, $$\max f = \frac{1+\sqrt{65}}8$$ $$\min f = \frac{1-\sqrt{65}}8$$

Proof:

$$a\sin x + b\cos x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin x + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x\right) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\theta)$$ where $\theta = \arctan \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$. Note $-1\le \sin(x+\theta)\le 1$. This proves our claim. We can also figure out that maximum occurs when $\sin(x+\theta)=1$ and minimum when $\sin(x+\theta)=-1$.
Thus, you can also figure where the $\max$ and $\min$ are attained.

Answer (score 1):

*(from one of my comments)* “Of course, the values of the tangent function can be “pushed through” with some work to obtain max/min values of the function (evaluate sine and cosine functions at the inverse-tangent values), $\ldots$”

What follows is probably not what the author intended, but I'm posting it on the off-chance that someone wants to see some details for what I suggested. My guess is that this problem was NOT intended to be a calculus problem, which in my opinion is a bit disingenuous to include in a calculus text without some kind of warning or prior expectation that non-calculus methods should sometimes be used.

First, solve $f'(x) = 0.$ Since $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\cos x \sin x - 2\cos 2x = -\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x - 2\cos 2x,$ we get $-\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x = 2 \cos 2x,$ or $\tan 2x = -8.$

The reason for converting $\cos x \sin x$ to $\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$ is that it allows us to get a quotient of sine and cosine having the same argument/input, which then allows us to put the equation into the form “trig function of something = a number”. If instead we use the double angle formula for $\cos 2x$ to rewrite the equation in terms of sine and cosine evaluated at $x,$ then we will get a trig equation that seems a lot more difficult to deal with -- doesn’t factor into a product equal to $0,$ so would have to express everything in terms of one trig function using $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1,$ resulting a somewhat messy radical equation.

Since $\tan 2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x},$ our last version of $f'(x) = 0$ becomes $\frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x} = -8,$ or $4\tan^2 x - \tan x - 4 = 0.$ Using the quadratic formula gives $\tan x = \frac{-(-1) \; \pm \; \sqrt{(-1)^2 - 4(4)(-4)}}{2(4)} = \frac{1 \; \pm \; \sqrt{65}}{2}.$

Let’s just deal with $\frac{1 \; + \; \sqrt{65}}{2}$ and see where that takes us. We have to evaluate $f(x)$ at $x = \arctan \left( \frac{1 \; + \; \sqrt{65}}{2} \right),$ which will involve evaluating sine and cosine for $x = \arctan \left(\frac{1 \; + \; \sqrt{65}}{2}\right).$ This can be done by a standard method using an appropriately labeled right triangle or by using an appropriate Pythagorean identity (e.g. see “Example 3: Evaluate a Mixed Composition of Trig Functions” [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20240321094000/https://www.andrews.edu/%7Erwright/Precalculus-RLW/Text/04-09.html)).

An “appropriately labeled right triangle” has an acute angle of $x$ and opposite side $1 + \sqrt{65}$ and adjacent side $8$ and hypothenuse $\sqrt{130 + 2\sqrt{65}},$ where the value of the hypothenuse is obtained from $\text{hyp}^2 = \text{opp}^2 + \text{adj}^2 = \left(1 + \sqrt{65}\right)^2 + 8^2.$

Since $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\cos^2 x - \sin 2x = \frac{1}{4}\cos^2 x - 2\sin x \cos x$ and $\cos x = \frac{\text{adj}}{\text{hyp}} = \frac{8}{\sqrt{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}}$ and $\sin x = \frac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{65}}{\sqrt{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}},$ we get

$$ f(x) \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}}\right)^2 \; - \; 2 \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{65}}{\sqrt{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}}\right) \left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}}\right) $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{64}{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}\right) \; - \; 16\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{65}}{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}\right) $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{16 - 16 - 16\sqrt{65}}{130 + 2\sqrt{65}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{-16\sqrt{65}}{130 + 2\sqrt{65}}  $$

Now rationalize the denominator to get

$$ \frac{-16\sqrt{65}(130 - 2\sqrt{65})}{(130 + 2\sqrt{65})(130 - 2\sqrt{65})} \;\; = \;\; \frac{-2080\sqrt{65} + 2080}{{130}^2 - (2\sqrt{65})^2}  $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{-2080(\sqrt{65} - 1)}{16640} \;\; = \;\; \frac{1 - \sqrt{65}}{8}  $$

At this point we need to determine whether this is a maximum or a minimum (or neither). I suppose we could use the 2nd derivative test -- find $f''(x)$ (not difficult) and evaluate it at $x = \arctan \left(\frac{1 \; + \; \sqrt{65}}{2}\right)$ using the numerical values we obtained above for $\cos x$ and $\sin x.$ Then there is the matter of dealing with the other value we found for $x,$ namely $x = \arctan \left(\frac{1 \; - \; \sqrt{65}}{2}\right).$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\cos^2 x $ in terms of  $\cos 2x$

Then you will get $f(x)$ in the form of $k + a \sin2x + b \cos2x$ where $a,b,k$  are constants.Then you can use the fact that the max value of
$a \sin\alpha + b \cos\alpha $ is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. So the maximum value becomes $k + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}. $

Answer (score 0):

Without using the result about $a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$, here is a solution.

Continue... So, $f^\prime(x)=0$ if $\tan(2x)=-8$. Then, $\cos(2x)=\pm1/\sqrt{65}$. Take $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\cos(2a)=+\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}}$$
$$\cos(2b)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}}$$
Then,
$$f^{\prime\prime}(x)=-\frac12\cos(2x)+4\sin(2x)=-\frac12\cos(2x)\left(1-8\tan(2x)\right)$$
so $f^{\prime\prime}(a)<0$ and $f^{\prime\prime}(b)>0$. Hence, $a$ is a point of local maximum and $b$ is a point of local minimum. Now, note
$$f(x)=\frac14\cos^2(x)-\sin(2x)=\frac14\left(\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}\right)-\cos(2x)\tan(2x)$$
Thus,
$$f(a)=\frac18\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}}\right)+\frac{8}{\sqrt{65}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{8}$$
$$f(b)=\frac18\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}}\right)-\frac{8}{\sqrt{65}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{65}}{8}$$
You can verify these are the global maximum and minimum.

Hope this helps. :)